# Removing nested elements with same class keeping the inner most one using JQUery

Tags: jquery

I've the following html -

```
<ul>
   <li class=".item">
      <a href="test">
         <li class=".item">
            <a href="test">
               <li class=".item">
                  <a href="http://test">
                        Real content 1
                  </a>
                </li>
            </a>
         </li>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class=".item">
      <a href="test">
         <li class=".item">
            <a href="test">
               <li class=".item">
                  <a href="http://test">
                       Real Content 2
                  </a>
                </li>
            </a>
         </li>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is the output rendered by an application. The li's are nested inside with the same class. I need to just have the innermost one and remove the dummy parents and get this -

```
<ul>
   <li class=".item">
      <a href="test">
         Real Content 1
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class=".item">
      <a href="test">
         Real Content 2
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this using JQuery?

Comment: HTML invalid. a contains nested a tags

Comment: I've mentioned that this the html rendered by an external application over which I've NO control. I completely agree that this is not a valid html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKxu5/7/)

```
$("ul >li").filter(function(){
      return $(this).text().trim() == ''
}).remove();

 $('ul li  a').filter(function(){
         return $(this).text().trim() == ''
}).remove();
```

​

Comment: I know that. As I mentioned this html is spitted by one external application and I'm trying to style it. I don't have control over the rendering of html by that application.

Comment: @NLV I re modified my code have look also attached jsfiddle link

Comment: @Sushil This definitely looks correct on the page, but the markup still has a bunch of empty <li>s... Can do something like this at the end to remove those: 

$('ul > li').not(':has(a)').remove();

Link to updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rKxu5/5/

Comment: @brandwaffle thanks for pointing out extra li and a. I modified my code.

Comment: @NLV I am sorry I re modified my code this time it should defiantly work.